# PHP cookie reading stopped working

Tags: php, cookies

For some reason this script stopped reading the cookie & is not displaying 'NO POP' or the 'POP CODE' messages the sine 2/3 week, The cookie 'faceupz' is set on my pc anyway, Anyone a idee how it make it work ?

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE['faceupz'] ) )
{
echo 'NO POP'; 
}
else
{
echo 'POP CODE';
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Array ( [PHPSESSID] => f6a765dd903eb92e5ab7adc2828b2113 [langedit] => [lang] => )

Comment: So... probably not in the request headers. Could you check those (firebug, or dev tools in chrome for instance). And are you sure it isn't path-related?

Comment: I am not sure the script was working for 3 months i did not change it just stopped working

Comment: ps no data on `echo $_COOKIE["faceupz"];`